# will xtile work?

Tags: 12.04, installation, deb, window-management

xtile is a kind of window tiling tool. I've tried to download the *.deb package from the following link:

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/x-tile-gnome-applet-for-your-panel-or-optionally-a-standalone-application.html

When I double-click on it from nautilus ubuntu software centre opens up and shows an internal error. Any headers on what the problem could be?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Download x-tile [From Here](http://www.giuspen.com/x-tile/#downl) Once it downloads probably to the Downloads folder,  press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
cd Downloads
```

Once you're in Downloads, do

```
sudo dpkg -i x-tile_2.3.1-1_all.deb
```

And that will install x-tile

Comment: Problem was with the package I had previously downloaded...it was in non-debian format